# How insert object Hibernate(JPA) when PK of my table is identity (sql server)

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

This is my Object that represent my table:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class Motivo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigomotivo;
    private String descricaomotivo;
    private Integer codrubricadominio;
    private String tipo;

}
```

My column `codigomotivo` in database is `identity`, she autoincrement values.
In this form, i receive error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.

this is a insert that hibernate generate in log:

```
Hibernate: insert into Motivo (codigomotivo, codrubricadominio, descricaomotivo, tipo) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
```

I Have tried too `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`
and receive this message in log:

> Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near
>   'value'

And too only `@GeneratedValue` and receive same error above.

How i can insert values in my table in this configuration PK in `Sql Server`?

Comment: After more try, i discovery tha Dialect was wrong, i change Dialect for `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect` it worked

Comment: which one you have before?

Answer (score 2):

Just change your dialect to:

```
org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```